# Global variables are being updated

Tags: python-2.7, namespaces

```
def is_safe(self,requesting_train_name,requesting_train_priority,requested_resources):
    # Initialize P1 & P0
    # We need to maintain an AR. 
    performer = requesting_train_name
    AR = set(filter(lambda x : G.node[x]['reservation'] <= requesting_train_priority, G.nodes()))
    P1 = []
    P0 = self.active_trains.keys()

    active_trains_trial = self.active_trains.copy()
    print active_trains_trial is self.active_trains

    # Update AR. Remove all elements of requested resources from AR
    AR.difference_update(set(requested_resources))

    # Provisionally updating OR
    print 'OR before update',self.active_trains[performer].OR
    active_trains_trial[performer].OR.update(set(requested_resources))
    print 'OR after update',self.active_trains[performer].OR
```

The 'OR before update' and 'OR after update' line should give the same results. This is not happening. The -- is -- statement returns False as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're modifying the same dictionary and the interpreter is behaving correctly.

```
>>> active_trains = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> active_trains_trial = active_trains
>>> active_trains_trial
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
>>> active_trains_trial['one'] = 1.5
>>> active_trains
{'two': 2, 'one': 1.5}
```

If you really need a separate dictionary you will have to create a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of **Aliasing**. `print active_trains_trial is active_trains` should print `True` though I expect you would want it to print `False`. This can be fixed by changing the statement

```
active_trains_trial = active_trains
```

to

```
active_trains_trial = active_trains.copy()
```

**Further Explanation:**

There are two kinds of objects in python: *immutable* and *mutable*. The value of **Immutable objects** can't be changed. Immutable objects include numeric values, strings, and tuples among others.

Instead of variables, python has **identifiers** which are simply names that point to objects. You can't change the value of an immutable object itself, but you can change which object an identifier points to. For example:

```
var = 3
var = 4
```

does not change the value of the int object `3` but rather reassigns the *identifier* `var` to the int object `4`.

**Aliasing** is when different names are given to *the same objects*.

```
var1 = 3
var2 = 3
```

is an example of aliasing the *immutable* object `3`. `var1` and `var2` are both the same object and this can be proved by testing to see if the `id`s are the same. This can be done two ways in python: `print var1 is var2` or `print id(var1) == id(var2)`. Both of those statements should print `True`.

However, this particular example only works with immutable objects. An example that would work with mutable and immutable objects would be:

```
var1 = <object>
var2 = var1
```

**Aliasing** is always safe with *imutable* objects because the value of the object itself will never be changed unexpectedly. For example:

```
var1 = 3
var2 = var1
var2 = 4
print var1
print var2
print var1 is var2
```

will produce the output

```
3
4
False
```

Notice how the *value* of `var1` did **not** change.

The value of **Mutable objects** on the other hand, **can** be changed. Mutable objects include lists and dictionaries among others.

```
L1 = [1, 2]
L2 = [1, 2]
L3 = L1
print L1 == L2
print L1 is L2
print L1 is L3
```

will produce the output

```
True
False
True
```

because although `L1` and `L2` have the same **values**, they are *not* the same **objects**. While `L3` was assigned **to** the object of `L1`, therefore they *are* the same object.

**Aliasing mutable objects** can be *very dangerous*. The reason for this is if you change the value of the object using one of its identifiers, *all* of the other identifiers' values will change as well.

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3]
L2 = L1
L2 = [1, 2]
print L1
print L2
print L1 is L2
```

will produce the output

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
True
```

Notice how the value of `L1` **did** change. This is because `L1` and `L2` are simply **aliases** for the *same **mutable** object*.

This can be avoided by creating what's known as **copies** of an object. With lists this can be done as: `L1 = <list>[:]`, and with dictionaries it can be done as: `d1 = <dict>.copy()`

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3]
L2 = L1[:]
L2 = [1, 2]
print L1
print L2
print L1 is L2
```

produces the output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
False
```

Notice how the value of `L1` didn't change, and L1 and L2 aren't the same object.

Comment: I've made the following changes in the code.
1 -> I've created a class in which this function and this dictionary "active_trains" resides.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find what the problem was.

When one creates a copy of a dictionary, one is creating a copy of the mapping without making a copy of the object that are being referenced. To explicate, when I checked if active_trains_local was active_trains, it turned out to be false as it was a shallow copy of active_trains. However, active_trains_local[performer] *was* active_trains[performer]. I finally wrote a duplicate_registery function which created a dictionary, iterated over active_trains, and populated the new dictionary.

```
def duplicate_registery(self):
    duplicate_active_trains = {}
    for name,dataset in self.active_trains.iteritems():
        duplicate_active_trains[name] = train_data(copy(dataset.MR),copy(dataset.OR))

    return duplicate_active_trains
```

The values in this case were namedtuples (from collections module). So,

```
for name,dataset in self.active_trains.iteritems():
        duplicate_active_trains[name] = copy(dataset)
```

did not work as it made a shallow copy of the 'dataset', but even in this shallow copy dataset.MR and dataset.OR referenced to the same object that the original dataset referred to.

Lesson learnt: Shallow copying a dictionary, gives shallow copy of a mapping. The duplicate mapping you end up with is still referencing the same objects. Special thanks @Thomson